# Why splitted on route level app still requests whole bundle.js file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, split, router

I still can't get the solution for this. I'm probably doing something wrong.

I splitted my app on route level (**react-router-4**) using dynamic import syntax. The bundle is chunked for smaller files (every one contains single route) and they are loaded asynchronously. The problem is, that even if it is splitted, the app still requests and loads whole **bundle.js** file:

```html
     0.b50665ddb9caa794e97e.js   965 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  
     1.c557a0622931c141e2ee.js   221 kB       1  [emitted]         
     2.b5c41d2de3e6395700d9.js  9.05 kB       2  [emitted]         
bundle.fd19428ab3151be11c7a.js   3.6 MB       3  [emitted]  [big]  bundle
                     style.css  21.8 kB       3  [emitted]         bundle
                    index.html  2.01 kB          [emitted]
```

My webpack configuration is following:

```html
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const VENDOR_LIBS = [
  'react', 'react-dom',
  'react-fontawesome',
  'react-redux',
  'react-router',
  'recharts',
  'redux',
  'redux-thunk',
  'axios',
  'babel-polyfill',
];

const config = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './src/index.js',
    vendor: VENDOR_LIBS
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.js$/,
        query: {
          plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        loaders: ['style-loader?sourceMap', 'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:4]!sass-loader?sourceMap'],
        test: /(styles\.sass)$/
      },
      {
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader!sass-loader"
        }),
        test: /(application.sass)$/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: { limit: 40000 }
          },
          'image-webpack-loader?{}'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    fs: "empty",
    net: "empty",
    dns: "empty"
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      async: true,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
    }),
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Thanks in advance for help. :)

// edit

So I composed all my 13 routes. This is the output:

```html
     8.8a79268f04b9c42a04c0.js   224 kB       8  [emitted]         
     0.9cb666849d998aa4188c.js  1.11 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  
     2.66db3b384c54d562a6af.js   936 kB       2  [emitted]  [big]  
     3.839b76b7e6fa0e65843f.js   335 kB       3  [emitted]  [big]  
     4.d6f21bdadc274b1050c7.js   297 kB       4  [emitted]  [big]  
     5.2e9d542b1923eecf17f9.js   242 kB       5  [emitted]         
     6.41769ae40fea916e2846.js   243 kB       6  [emitted]         
     7.b0aaa53d5665a9b7162f.js   242 kB       7  [emitted]         
     1.ad41e6983002b90f9116.js   869 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  
     9.7c54c61ee64fbe8357fc.js  99.4 kB       9  [emitted]         
    10.b95f217e8602aa4f0762.js  90.4 kB      10  [emitted]         
    11.fec87d07731569740d96.js   133 kB      11  [emitted]         
    12.4e6ff6abecef8311d153.js  4.69 kB      12  [emitted]         
bundle.6b0bbc0e63449de93ddf.js  1.01 MB      13  [emitted]  [big]  bundle
vendor.71438b5cd576c98978b3.js   715 kB      14  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
                     style.css  21.8 kB      13  [emitted]         bundle
                    index.html  2.09 kB          [emitted]
```

For comparison, I commented some routes and also async loaded components and this is the output:

```html
                         Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
     0.4820b11bd5c307396aaa.js   242 kB       0  [emitted]         
     1.386b1b1e2a78ab016aaf.js  99.4 kB       1  [emitted]         
     2.fd099c57a7f2fe91a220.js  4.69 kB       2  [emitted]         
bundle.62712758d7ba025b716c.js     1 MB       3  [emitted]  [big]  bundle
vendor.7fc364f5f9b15c408351.js   715 kB       4  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
                     style.css  21.8 kB       3  [emitted]         bundle
                    index.html  2.09 kB          [emitted]
```

Bundle.js file seems to be still the same size...

Also, added .babelrc file:

```html
{
  "plugins" : ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

Comment: What is inside your bundle.js? All you are doing is fine but, there still code that is not async, so it has to bundle and fetch every single time. I also don't see the ` "syntax-dynamic-import"` plugin for babel

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input Matheus. My syntax-dynamic-import plugin stays in .babelrc file.

Comment: Uhm... ok, so you are fine... What else is being inside your bundle.js? Sometimes makes sense the content in there, double check please. It should not have what is being async loaded. I'm almost certain that it has vendor content in there.

Comment: @MatheusSilva I edited my question with some output information, could you check it?

Comment: I have no idea though. Your routes for sure are not going inside the boundle, otherwise it would be more than 1.1M. Check if vendors are going inside. You can prettify the bundle.js and see if for sure your async things are there.

Comment: @MatheusSilva You are right, my routes are not inside bundle. I tested it by importing one route component synchronously (then bundle growed up). But, does that mean that the code that is not used in my routes, goes to bundle.js?

Comment: Not. It just means that, the code that is not loaded async (since not all your application is lazy-loaded), it goes in there. Read more about webpack, it is a bad practice to have vendors as entry points.